# java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So I'm getting this error message from the android market?
What does it mean?

Also do all apps crash??

Thanks for looking. :)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tmm.android.driving/com.tmm.android.driving.QuestionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tmm.android.driving.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:44)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Please add QuestionActivity class. Specially onCreate method

Comment: The information provided asks for guesswork. Please explain in more details what is the issue you're having, and provide code where applicable.

Comment: most likely you are using `findViewById` before `setContentView` so it returns null and then you are using this null value `x = findViewById(...); x.setSomething(...) <= NPE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.tmm.android.driving.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:44)

On this line you are using a value which is `null`, most likely you are using a value which hasn't been initialised.

> Do all apps crash?

All applications can throw an error if they have a bug.  This bug shouldn't cause other applications to report errors.  BTW  a crash is much more severe than this and you shouldn't be able to crash a Java/Android application unless there is a bug in the JVM/DVM.

Comment: Thanks I'll looking into that now.

Comment: I know this might be a stupid question but.... This is on a quiz app, Could this error be from someone exiting the quiz without finishing it?

Comment: If you don't check the values you get from libraries or user input correctly, you can get this error.  If you check the results you get, you should never see this, unless there is bug in a library you use and it gets this error (in which case you can still catch/handle it)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you have written your app but its unlikely.